# ArgsTable storybook 6 MDX

Tags: storybook, lit-element, mdxjs

I am trying to insert ArgsTable inside an MDX file but it does not show the table.
The components are developed with Litelement.
Have you also encountered the same problem?

```
<ArgsTable story="name-story" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use the ArgdTable in MDX, you need to do this:

```js
<Story name="Foo Bar"> ... </Story>

<ArgsTable story="Foo Bar" />
```

What is the name on your Story?